# Anyone know this book with dragons and a pregnant girl?

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

So I remember reading a book about dragons about 10 years or more ago and I don't know who wrote it or what it's called.
The only thing I can recall is that there was dragons, and a pregnant lady who was carrying a child that will help the dragons. All the villagers wanted to murder her as nobody wanted dragons around. People hunted dragons for scales and other parts to sell...

IDK, if anyone has any ideas please share!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You may be interested in reading [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) on how best to handle asking a story-ID question :-)

Comment: Ticks some of the boxes, but far too recent; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22717692-sacrificed-to-the-dragon

Comment: Lots of dragons and a pregant heroine; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/703323.Dragon_s_Milk

Comment: What about series [Dragonriders of Pern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern)? But I am not sure about the pregnancy [maybe this piece](https://www.amazon.com/Dragons-Time-Dragonriders-Anne-McCaffrey/dp/0345500903).

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on this question and I may have an answer.

Could you be thinking of "Mistress of Dragons", by Margaret Weis ?

Contrary what the title and the author may suggest it is not part of the Dragonlance cycle. It is the first volume of the Dragonvarld trilogy.

It was published in 2003 so that fits. It has a pregnant woman (carrying twins though, but if I recall correctly that is only made clear at the very end of the book). There is a power struggle going on within the dragon society, between "good" and "evil" dragons and humans are caught in the middle.

[Dragonvarld on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonvarld)